# What is the message that the second example in [class.virtual]/2 is trying to convey?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

What is the message that the second example in [[class.virtual]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#2.example-2) is trying to convey?

If I declare a `D d;` object below and call `d.f();` the code will not compile due to the ambiguity between `A::f` and `C::f`. Then, what is the purpose of this example?

```
struct A { virtual void f(); };
struct B : A { };
struct C : A { void f(); };
struct D : B, C { };            // OK: A​::​f and C​::​f are the final overriders
                                // for the B and C subobjects, respectively
```

Comment: Guess the point is that `d.B::f()` and `d.C::f()` are both valid, and different.

Comment: The purpose of the example is to show when inheritance can cause ambiguous methods.

Answer (score -1):

I think, the example goes to show that it's OK to inherit from two classes which override the same virtual function.

`D` does not contain *final overriders* for `f()`, so the program is well-formed. You can call `C::f()` and `B::f()` respectively.

Comment: As far as I can understand `D` contains two final overriders for `f()`, `A::f` and `C::f`, otherwise, the snippet that I mentioned in my question would not show an error indicating the ambiguity between the two member functions.

Comment: @JohnKalane `D` inherits from `B` and `C`, so it doesn't contain `A::f`. There is only one final overrider.

Comment: @JohnKalane I read it differently, as there are two subobject within D, so D does not have two final overriders.

Comment: @SergeyA [This sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#2.sentence-3) in [class.virtual]/2 seems to confirm that both `A::f` and `C::f` are final overriders for `f` in class `D`. Note that `D` doesn't need to contain a member function `f` in order for `f` to be considered a final overrider for `D`.